# "cannot load such file -- action_controller/request" when require 'opensocial'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, opensocial

After 
gem install rails
gem install opensocial

I tried to do require 'opensocial' under irb.

but the error occured.

> > require 'opensocial'
> >     LoadError: no such file to load -- action_controller/request
> >         from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
> >         from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth/request_proxy/action_controller_request.rb:3
> >         from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
> >         from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/opensocial-0.0.4/lib/opensocial/auth/action_controller_request.rb:27
> >         from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
> >         from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/opensocial-0.0.4/lib/opensocial.rb:19
> >         from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
> >         from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
> >         from (irb):4
> >         from :0

And when I am using it under ror(add gem 'opensocial' to Gemfile, then rails server), the same error also occurs.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of ruby installed?

Comment: How can I confirm whether I have multiple versions of ruby? And If I have, What should I do to solve this problem?